# Collecting environment content with support for xparse arguments

Tags: environments, latex3, xparse

I'm trying to create an environment which uses `xparse` style arguments but I have to be able to use the whole environment content in the environment definition, e.g. as an argument.

Ideally I'd like to write something like

```
\DeclareCollectedDocumentEnvironment { env } { o } {
    Make use of optional Argument #1 and Content \CollectedBody.
}
\begin{env}[optional]
    content
\end{env}
```

Is there a reason, why `xparse` doesn't provide something like this?

Using `\NewEnviron` from the `environ` package does not work for me, because I'm reliant on some of the argument-parsing features `xparse` provides.

Currently I've got this working:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{environ}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\DeclareDocumentCommand { \myenv } { o u\q_nil } {
    opt:~#1 \\
    content:~#2
}
\cs_set:Npn \myenv_collect:n #1 {
    \myenv #1 \q_nil
}
\makeatletter
\DeclareDocumentEnvironment { env } { } {
    \Collect@Body \myenv_collect:n
} { }
\makeatother

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{env}[99]
    With optional argument
\end{env}

\begin{env}
    Without optional argument
\end{env}

\end{document}
```

This however has some flaws:

- Multiple paragraphs inside the environment cause an infinite loop
- Nesting does not work as expected

I've also tried to declare the arguments for `\DeclareDocumentEnvironment` and somehow pass them onto `\myenv_collect:n`, but the behaviour of `\Collect@Body` made it difficult.

Is there a solution to my problem, preferably a latex3 one?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Updated answer (March 2019)

With the release 2019-03-05 release of `xparse`, the functionality of `environ` has been implemented, with some adaptations. See below for a description.

The above code can be reduced to

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{xparse} % uncomment if you have LaTeX between 2019-03-05 and 2020-09-30

\NewDocumentEnvironment{env}{O{default}+b}
 {Do something with #1 and #2}
 {}

\begin{document}

\begin{env}
What is this?

Another paragraph.
\end{env}

\begin{env}[foo]
What is this?

Another paragraph.
\end{env}

\end{document}
```

Some notes: the argument specifier `b` denotes the body of the environment, which will be then collected as a macro argument, just like `environ` did. There is no `\BODY` to use: in this case `b` is the second argument, so one refers to it as `#2`.

The “end part” is to be specified, although it will be usually empty.

If paragraphs are expected in the body, the argument should be specified as `+b`, like all other “long arguments”.

[image]

### Original answer

An interface similar to `\NewEnviron` would be a welcome addition to `xparse`; but you can use it indirectly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,environ}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{env}{ O{default} }
 {\Environenv{#1}}
 {\endEnvironenv}

\NewEnviron{Environenv}[1]
 {Do something with #1 and \BODY}

\begin{document}

\begin{env}
What is this?

Another paragraph.
\end{env}

\begin{env}[foo]
What is this?

Another paragraph.
\end{env}

\end{document}
```

If you call the command form of `Environenv`, it will know what environment it's been called in. That's the same trick for defining environments containing `align` in `amsmath`.

Comment: Is there an 'xparse only' approach now (3 years later)?

Comment: @Andy Now there is news! :-)

Comment: @egreg I saw the announcement of this on comp.text.tex, but the announcement has since disappeared. I'm using the 2019 TeXLive pretest, though I don't believe the new version has been installed.

Comment: @sgmoye Use tlmgr to update it.

Comment: @egreg Well, I have been doing just that (for 2019), successfully, though tlmgr.log makes no mention of xparse. Just ran `sudo tlmgr update xparse` and got this back: `tlmgr: xparse mentioned, but neither new nor forcibly removed`. This is certainly not critical, just curious. The fact that the announcement is now missing on CTT suggests that it was withdrawn?

Comment: @sgmoye `tlmgr update l3kernel l3experimental l3packages`. The revision number is 50246