# How can I control the minimum number of lines (rows) that should be kept together when a page break is necessary?

Tags: spacing, line-breaking, page-breaking

## What to do when tabular alignment just doesn't cut it?

I designed (perhaps not efficiently or with the "right" approach, yet using some helpful LaTeX3 answers from egreg) a way to enter data into an almost table-like list.

The main issue is that

- my "table" can break where the table's footer bar occurs as demonstrated in the example.
- Also, it can break just after the footer bar's information, just before the caption.

This results in a caption or footer and caption that is separated from the table by a page break. I know that I could just wrap things with minipages, but I need breakable text, because some of these parameter lists are very long.

## Criteria

1. Every item is page-breakable except the last two items, which must stay with the table's footer and caption.
2. The descriptions should be in paragraph format under each item (as I have demonstrated in the example)
3. `jkodescriptionlist` and `\jkoitem` have a flexible number of arguments (only the first two get aligned left).

What I would like is to define a minimum number lines (`jkoitem`s) that should be kept with the table's footer bar. (For that matter, a break should also never occur immediately after the table's header bar.) **If a page break is necessary right where the table's footer is or caption, a page break will occur, but it will take a few of the items with it onto the next page.**

*Note:* I was able to keep the table's footer bar and data together by using `\\*` which corresponds to `\vadjust{\nobreak\vskip<length>}`

**I am also open to suggestions as to how I could implement this entire thing better.** I would think that the solution deals with glue. As cfr suggested, a longtable environment might work, but I do not know how to implement this layout with longtable without making the source code a total mess. UPDATE: I forgot that I had previously asked a question regarding tables and LaTeX3, which might come in handy here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/243627/13552^. I remember just giving up because of a time constraint and I was never able to implement the longtable version.

## Code

I am open to suggestions

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\jkotabcap}[1]{\captionof{table}{#1}\bigskip}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareDocumentEnvironment{jkodescriptionlist}{O{}O{}}%
    {%
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{\heavyrulewidth}\\*
\noindent\textbf{\textcolor{red}{#1}}\\*
\noindent\rule[2mm]{\textwidth}{\lightrulewidth}\par
    }%
    {%
    % Some glue should probably go here that prevents the bottom of the table from being alone on a page but I am not sure how to do this.
    % Do I need \leavevmode\vadjust{\penalty 10000} or something similar?
    {\nopagebreak\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{\heavyrulewidth}\\*
     \tiny #2\par}
    }%

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\jkoitem}{O{}m}{% Optional:comma list of values; mandatory:description
\noindent\dojkoitemargs:n{#1}\vadjust{\nobreak\vskip .1ex}
\null\hspace{2em}\par\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-4em\relax}{\footnotesize#2}\vskip 1.7ex plus 2ex % Description Format
    }%

\clist_new:N\jkoitemargs
\cs_new_protected:Nn\dojkoitemargs:n{{%
\clist_set:Nn\jkoitemargs{#1}%
\textbf{\clist_item:Nn \jkoitemargs {1}},~\clist_item:Nn \jkoitemargs {2} \hfill
\int_step_inline:nnnn {3}{1}{\clist_count:N \jkoitemargs}
    {%
        \int_compare:nTF { ##1 = \clist_count:N \jkoitemargs }
            {\clist_item:Nn \jkoitemargs {##1}}
            {\clist_item:Nn \jkoitemargs {##1},~}
    }
}}%

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
% Syntax
%\jkoitem[Whatever fields are needed]
%{Description}
\section{Introduction}
\subsection{This Fun Document}
\lipsum[1-2]
Hello\\ % <-- Uncomment this line to push the entire bottom of the table to another page.
\begin{jkodescriptionlist}[HL7-Path, Name \hfill R/O, Rep\#][\textbf{R/0} = Required/Optional, \textbf{R} = Required,
\textbf{O} = Optional, \textbf{RO} = Required if known,
\textbf{REP\#} = Repitition, \textbf{Y} = entry can be
taken from the list, \textbf{N} = Individual Values,
\textbf{Number} = Maximum length of the list]
\jkoitem[MSH-6-2,homeCommunityID,R]
{OID of the affinity domain where the document will be stored.}
\jkoitem[MSH-19,languageCode,R]
{Specifies the human language of the document. Format according RFC-3066.}
\jkoitem[PID-3,patientInfo.socialSecurityNumber,R]
{Social security number of the patient. Important: The social security number will be
identified within the list of patient
identifiers (PID-3) by the OID of the social security association.}
\jkoitem[PID-3,patientInfo.sourcePatientID,R]
{Patient identifier of the local CIS/RIS/PACS…Important: The Patient Identifier
will be identified within the list of patient identifiers (PID-3) by the identifier type code PI.}
\jkoitem[PID-5-1,patientInfo.familyName,R]
{Family name of the patient.}
\jkoitem[PID-5-2,patientInfo.givenName,R]
{Given name of the patient.}
\jkoitem[PID-5-3,patientInfo.secondAndFurtherNames[0],O]
{Second and further names of the patient}
\end{jkodescriptionlist}
\jkotabcap{Fun Mapping Data.}
\label{Table:Fun Mapping Data}

\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

---

## Semi-Successful Revamp TeX > LaTeX from wipet's Code

I am not completely satisfied because it is not as flexible with the `\jkoitem` arguments as the original. For example, my `\jkoitem` can support an arbitrary number of arguments (until they become unaesthetic). This code only supports 3 aesthetically pleasing arguments. Also, I am not exactly sure whether I understand what is going on, but I made it to page 112 of the TeXBook, and tried implementing some of the things I learned for breaking and paragraph shapes.

## Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcount\jcodenum

\def\jcode[#1]#2[#3]#4\endjcode{\goodbreak\hbox{}\par
    \hrule\medskip\hbox to\hsize{\bf #1}\medskip\hrule\medskip
    {\jcodenum=0
     \def\jkoitem[##1]##2{\advance\jcodenum by1 } % Dummy function just tallies up jkoitem's as they are parsed
     \typeout{**** Value of Counter (before first call of body 4): \the\jcodenum}% Print count of jcodenum at this point to log 
     #4 % prints contents of jcode=nothing because jkoitem prints nothing, serves to increment \jcodenum (see log output)
     \typeout{**** Value of Counter (after first call of body 4): \the\jcodenum}% Print count of jcodenum at this point to log 
     \interlinepenalty=10000% value of the penalty (node) added after each line of a paragraph.
     \let\jkoitem=\jkoitemx% Reassign jkoitem to jkoitemx, passing all args properly 
     #4 %This #4 represents the jkoitems with the new definition? Commenting this out erases content
         \typeout{**** Value of Counter (after redefinition and new call of body 4): \the\jcodenum}% Print count of jcodenum at this point to log 
     \medskip\hrule\nobreak\smallskip \tiny \noindent#3\bigskip\par}
}
\def\jkoitemx[#1,#2,#3]#4{\goodbreak\par \noindent{\bf#1}, \ignorespaces#2\hfill #3\par\nobreak
    \hangindent=\parindent{\footnotesize #4\par}% This #4 represents the descriptions
    \advance\jcodenum by-1% descrease count while it is increased
    \typeout{**** Value of Counter (inside of jkoitemx): \the\jcodenum}% Print count of jcodenum at this point to log 
    \ifnum\jcodenum<2 \nobreak \fi
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\jcode[HL7-Path, Name \hfill R/O, Rep\#]
      [{\bf R/0}~=~Required/Optional, {\bf R}~=~Required,
       {\bf O}~=~Optional, {\bf RO}~=~Required if known, 
       {\bf REP\#}~=~Repitition, {\bf Y}~=~entry can be taken from the list,
       {\bf N}~=~Individual Values, {\bf Number}~=~Maximum length of the list]
\jkoitem[MSH-6-2,homeCommunityID,R]
{OID of the affinity domain where the document will be stored.}
\jkoitem[MSH-19,languageCode,R]
{Specifies the human language of the document. Format according RFC-3066.}
\jkoitem[PID-3,patientInfo.socialSecurityNumber,R]
{Social security number of the patient. Important: The social security
number will be
identified within the list of patient
identifiers (PID-3) by the OID of the social security association.}
\jkoitem[PID-3,patientInfo.sourcePatientID,R]
{Patient identifier of the local CIS/RIS/PACS…Important: The Patient
Identifier
will be identified within the list of patient identifiers (PID-3) by the
identifier type code PI.}
\jkoitem[PID-5-1,patientInfo.familyName,R]
{Family name of the patient.}
\jkoitem[PID-5-2,patientInfo.givenName,R]
{Given name of the patient.}
\jkoitem[PID-5-3,patientInfo.secondAndFurtherNames{[0]},O]
{Second and further names of the patient}
\jkoitem[PID-5-3,patientInfo.secondAndFurtherNames{[0]},O]
{Second and further names of the patient}
\jkoitem[PID-5-3,patientInfo.secondAndFurtherNames{[0]},O]
{Second and further names of the patient}
\jkoitem[PID-5-3,patientInfo.secondAndFurtherNames{[0]},O]
{Second and further names of the patient}
\jkoitem[PID-5-3,patientInfo.secondAndFurtherNames{[0]},O]
{Second and further names of the patient}
\endjcode
%\bye
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

### Related Log Entries:

```
**** Value of Counter (before first call of body 4): 0
**** Value of Counter (after first call of body 4): 11
**** Value of Counter (inside of jkoitemx): 10
**** Value of Counter (inside of jkoitemx): 9
**** Value of Counter (inside of jkoitemx): 8
**** Value of Counter (inside of jkoitemx): 7
**** Value of Counter (inside of jkoitemx): 6
**** Value of Counter (inside of jkoitemx): 5
**** Value of Counter (inside of jkoitemx): 4
**** Value of Counter (inside of jkoitemx): 3
**** Value of Counter (inside of jkoitemx): 2
**** Value of Counter (inside of jkoitemx): 1
**** Value of Counter (inside of jkoitemx): 0
**** Value of Counter (after redefinition and new call of body 4): 0
```

## Output

[image]

---

## A Revamped Approach using Longtable (response to cfr's comment)

*Updated January 7, 2016*

Issues:

- col1 not bold (because I am using `\clist_use:Nn \jkoitemargs { & }` instead of `\textbf{\clist_item:Nn \jkoitemargs {1}}`)
- col3 not right aligning correctly
- a page break can potentially occur between a row and its description (FIXED: `\\` to `\\*`)
- Tabular alignment simply does not look as good as the original.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{mytable}{ O{} }
  {
    \clist_set:Nn \jkotableargs { #1 }
    \begin{longtable}{llrr}
    \clist_use:Nn \jkoitemargs { & } \endhead
  }
  {
    \end{longtable}
  }

\clist_new:N\jkoitemargs
\clist_new:N\jkotableargs
\NewDocumentCommand{\myitem}{ O{} m }
  {
  \clist_set:Nn \jkoitemargs { #1 }
  \clist_use:Nn \jkoitemargs { & }\\*
  \multicolumn{ 4 } {@{}l@{}}
    {
      \hspace{\parindent}
      \parbox{\dim_eval:n { \textwidth-\parindent } } {\footnotesize #2}
    }
  \\[\normalbaselineskip]
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
\begin{mytable}[HL7-Path, Name, R/O, Rep\#]
\myitem[col1,col2,col3,col4]{description on new row}
\myitem[MSH-6-2,homeCommunityID,R/O,Rep\#]{OID of the affinity domain where the document will be stored.}
\end{mytable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you use **longtable**, then you can specify a table footer for each page and/or a distinct footer for the final page, if desired. (The same for headers, with a distinct one for the first page, if wanted.) The package will then automatically insert page breaks in a way that allows space for the footer on each page and/or the footer on the last page. I imagine this would be easier than rolling your own, but perhaps the **needspace** package would help if you really need the latter.

Comment: @cfr The problem with using tables is that the syntax is so bad for writing descriptions in the last column (which I don't even have in a column as you can see in the output). Tables aren't really good for paragraph data. But maybe I should reconsider using it. Maybe I can even wrap the longtable by my environment.

Comment: @macmadness86 You copied my macro `\jokitemx` but you added `\goodbreak` before `\par` at the starting point of this macro. This `\goodbreak` negates all endeavour with `\nobreak`. Because `\nobreak\goodbreak` in a sequence acts like `\goodbreak`. Remove `\goodbreak`.

Comment: @macmadness86 I don't understand why you takes useless effort with re-writing the idea to LaTeX3 language. TeX primitives work much more flexible. You need no more than to copy my macros to your LaTeX (if you are using LaTeX).

Comment: @wipet Well, I do not know if that is true due to my limited knowledge of TeX. I do know that my code allows for more than three arguments in the jkoenv and jkoitem. LaTeX3 loops them. Yours is hardcoded. (I mentioned this in the question) I am dealing with a situation where other people need to be able to understand the userlevel LaTeX `\begin{env}\end{env}` commands. As long as I can make it user-friendly from the document side, I am fine with TeX. I can't get that working. I am preparing another question about counters at the moment that may clear up some of my misunderstanding.

Comment: @macmadness86 I don't understand what you mean as "more arguments", "aesthetic argument" etc. Please, be more specific. If I understand this then I can do this using TeX primitives without problems. You can use my email.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can start wit experimenting with the following code

```
\newcount\jcodenum

\def\jcode[#1]#2[#3]#4\endjcode{\par
    \hrule\medskip\hbox to\hsize{\bf #1}\medskip\hrule\medskip
    {\jcodenum=0
     \def\jkoitem[##1]##2{\advance\jcodenum by1 }#4
     \interlinepenalty=10000 \let\jkoitem=\jkoitemx #4
     \medskip\hrule\nobreak\medskip #3\par}
}
\def\jkoitemx[#1,#2,#3]#4{\par \noindent{\bf#1}, \ignorespaces#2\hfill #3\par\nobreak
    #4\par
    \advance\jcodenum by-1 \ifnum\jcodenum<2 \nobreak \fi
}

\jcode[HL7-Path, Name \hfill R/O, Rep\#]
      [{\bf R/0} = Required/Optional, {\bf R} = Required,
       {\bf O} = Optional, {\bf RO} = Required if known, 
       {\bf REP\#} = Repitition, {\bf Y} = entry can be taken from the list,
       {\bf N} = Individual Values, {\bf Number} = Maximum length of the list]
\jkoitem[MSH-6-2,homeCommunityID,R]
{OID of the affinity domain where the document will be stored.}
\jkoitem[MSH-19,languageCode,R]
{Specifies the human language of the document. Format according RFC-3066.}
\jkoitem[PID-3,patientInfo.socialSecurityNumber,R]
{Social security number of the patient. Important: The social security
number will be
identified within the list of patient
identifiers (PID-3) by the OID of the social security association.}
\jkoitem[PID-3,patientInfo.sourcePatientID,R]
{Patient identifier of the local CIS/RIS/PACS…Important: The Patient
Identifier
will be identified within the list of patient identifiers (PID-3) by the
identifier type code PI.}
\jkoitem[PID-5-1,patientInfo.familyName,R]
{Family name of the patient.}
\jkoitem[PID-5-2,patientInfo.givenName,R]
{Given name of the patient.}
\jkoitem[PID-5-3,patientInfo.secondAndFurtherNames{[0]},O]
{Second and further names of the patient}
\endjcode

\bye
```

You can try this in plain TeX. To rewrite this for LaTeX is simple exercise. I'll do not this because I don't support LaTeX.

The paragraphs are not breakable between lines and the last two items plus footer are not breakable too because of the test `\ifnum\jcodenum<2 \nobreak \fi`.

Comment: It's ok to use TeX. In fact, I've been reading through the TeXBook. I think I might have outgrown LaTeX. Without truly understanding TeX, I do not think I can effectively code in LaTeX (unfortunately).

Comment: I don't get why you used jkoitem and jkoitemx. Why not just use the if/then logic in jkoitem? Is this understanding correct: you  define an unbreakable \jkoitem that assigns itself to \jkoitemx that becomes breakable if the count is < 2?

Comment: The text with `\jkoitem, \jkoitem, ...` (i. e. `#4`) is processed twice. First with meaning of `\jkoitem`: print nothing, only increase `\jcodenum`. Now, the number of items is know. Second processing is with meaning of `\jkoitemx`: print all and decrease `\jcodenum`, append `\nobreak` if `\jcodenum<2`.

Comment: I get that #1 and #3 correspond to `\jcode[HL7-Path, Name \hfill R/O, Rep\#]` and everything in the next `[]`, respectively, but what do `#2` and `#4` represent in `jcode`? Maybe you could look at my attempt at translating your code into LaTeX (bottom of my question).

Comment: The `#2` in `\jcode` is usually space between first and second `[...] [...]`. And `#4` is whole text (all `\jokitem`s) separated by `\endjcode`

Comment: Ah, I see. You'd need to know the total num of items…so you loop through all items first by using `#4`. You need `\jkoitem` to count up to the total. You need `\jkoitemx` to count down to trigger the alternate glue only when reaching the last two items. I am not sure how to do this in LaTeX2 or LaTeX3.

Comment: LaTeX2 uses TeX primitives. My macro uses TeX primitives. This means that you can use this macro directly in LaTeX2, only slight modification is needed (maybe).

Answer (score 1):

## SOLVED Explanation of wipet's answer

*UPDATED January 11, 2016:*

The following code demonstrates a solution that counts each item within the environment. **It also demonstrates which types of environment's support this technique.** It is not supported by the `\newenvironment` macro or the `xparse \NewDocumentEnvironment` macro, because the content is inaccessible like it is in TeX. The only way to do it in LaTeX is to use the `environ` package's `\NewEnviron` combined with the `\BODY` macro to insert the environment's contents.

The trick is to tally up the number of `\additem`s and then redefine `\additem` to subtract from the sum of `\additem`s stored in the counter. An if/then statement checks to see whether the environment reaches the last `\additem` (`\ifnum\counter<2 \nobreak \fi`).  So, when there is one item (in other words, the counter hits 1), add a `\nobreak` (`\penalty \@M`/`\penalty 10000`) into the mix, which keeps the second to last item and the last item together on the next page. Ingenious! Thank you wipet!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcount\texcounter
\newcounter{latexNewEnvironcounter}
\newcounter{latexcounter}
\newcounter{latexthreecounter}

% TeX Syntax
\def\texenv#1\endtexenv{
  \def\additem[##1]##2{\advance\texcounter by1 }
  \typeout{**** Value texcounter (before first call of body): \the\texcounter} % Should be 0
  #1 % Typeset body of env
  \typeout{**** Value texcounter (after first call of body): \the\texcounter} % Should be 3
  \let\additem=\additemtex
  #1 % Retypeset body of env with new definition of \additem (\additemx)
  }

% environ Package NewEnviron
\NewEnviron{NewEnvironenv}{% environ package is the only way I know how to grab the body like in TeX
  \def\additem[##1]##2{\addtocounter{latexNewEnvironcounter}{1}}
  \typeout{**** Value latexNewEnvironcounter (before first call of body): \the\value{latexNewEnvironcounter}} % Should be 0
  \BODY % Typeset body of env
  \typeout{**** Value latexNewEnvironcounter (after first call of body): \the\value{latexNewEnvironcounter}} % Should be 3
  \let\additem=\additemlatexNewEnviron
  \BODY % Retypeset body of env with new definition of \additem (\additemx)
}{}

% LaTeX2e Syntax
\newenvironment{latexenv}{% Not supported because #1 cannot contain the body of the environment like in TeX
  \def\additem[##1]##2{\addtocounter{latexcounter}{1}}
  \typeout{****  Value latexcounter (before first call of body): \the\value{latexcounter}} % Should be 0
  %#1
  \typeout{**** Value latexcounter (after first call of body): \the\value{latexcounter}} % Should be 3
  \let\additem=\additemlatex
}{}

% LaTeX3 Syntax
\NewDocumentEnvironment{latexthreeenv}{}{% Not supported because #1 cannot contain the body of the environment like in TeX
  \def\additem[##1]##2{\addtocounter{latexthreecounter}{1}}
  \typeout{****  Value latexthreecounter (before first call of body): \the\value{latexthreecounter}} % Should be 0
  %#1
  \typeout{**** Value latexthreecounter (after first call of body): \the\value{latexthreecounter}} % Should be 3
  \let\additem=\additemlatexthree
}{}

% additem redefinition for TeX
\def\additemtex[#1,#2,#3]#4{\par \noindent{\bf#1}, \ignorespaces#2\hfill
    \def\comma{\def\comma{, }}\listargs #3,,\par\nobreak%Redefine comma to use space, see \listargs
    \hangindent=\parindent{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-\parindent-1cm\relax}{\footnotesize #4}\par}% This #4 represents the descriptions
    \typeout{**** Value texcounter (inside additemx): \the\texcounter}% Print count
    \advance\texcounter by-1 % descrease count while it is increased
    \ifnum\texcounter<2 \nobreak \fi
}
\def\listargs#1,{\ifx,#1,\else\comma\ignorespaces#1\expandafter\listargs\fi}% Redefine args to user spaces


% additem redefinition for NewEnviron
\def\additemlatexNewEnviron[#1,#2,#3]#4{\par \noindent{\bf#1}, \ignorespaces#2\hfill
    \def\comma{\def\comma{, }}\listargs #3,,\par\nobreak%Redefine comma to use space, see \listargs
    \hangindent=\parindent{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-\parindent-1cm\relax}{\footnotesize #4}\par}% This #4 represents the descriptions
    \typeout{**** Value latexNewEnvironcounter (inside additemlatexNewEnviron): \the\value{latexNewEnvironcounter}} % Print Count
    \addtocounter{latexNewEnvironcounter}{-1} % descrease count while it is increased
    \ifnum\latexNewEnvironcounter<2 \nobreak \fi
}

% additem redefinition for LaTeX2e
\def\additemlatex[#1,#2,#3]#4{\par \noindent{\bf#1}, \ignorespaces#2\hfill
    \def\comma{\def\comma{, }}\listargs #3,,\par\nobreak%Redefine comma to use space, see \listargs
    \hangindent=\parindent{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-\parindent-1cm\relax}{\footnotesize #4}\par}% This #4 represents the descriptions
    \typeout{**** Value latexcounter (inside additemlatex): \the\value{latexcounter}} % Print Count
    \addtocounter{latexcounter}{-1} % descrease count while it is increased
    \ifnum\latexcounter <2 \nobreak \fi
}


% additem redefinition for LaTeX3
\def\additemlatexthree[#1,#2,#3]#4{\par \noindent{\bf#1}, \ignorespaces#2\hfill
    \def\comma{\def\comma{, }}\listargs #3,,\par\nobreak%Redefine comma to use space, see \listargs
    \hangindent=\parindent{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-\parindent-1cm\relax}{\footnotesize #4}\par}% This #4 represents the descriptions
    \typeout{**** Value latexthreecounter (inside additemlatexthree): \the\value{latexthreecounter}} % Print Count
    \addtocounter{latexthreecounter}{-1} % descrease count while it is increased
    \ifnum\latexthreecounter<2 \nobreak \fi
}


\begin{document}

\section{Supported}
\subsection{\TeX}
\texenv
\additem[arg1,arg2,arg3]{A nice description. Value texcounter: \the\texcounter}
\additem[arg1,arg2,arg3]{A nice description. Value texcounter: \the\texcounter}
\additem[arg1,arg2,arg3]{A nice description. Value texcounter: \the\texcounter}
\endtexenv
\subsection{\texttt{environ} Package}
\begin{NewEnvironenv}
\additem[arg1,arg2,arg3]{A nice description. Value latexNewEnvironmentcounter: \the\value{latexNewEnvironcounter}}
\additem[arg1,arg2,arg3]{A nice description. Value latexNewEnvironmentcounter: \the\value{latexNewEnvironcounter}}
\additem[arg1,arg2,arg3]{A nice description. Value latexNewEnvironmentcounter: \the\value{latexNewEnvironcounter}}
\end{NewEnvironenv}

\section{Unsupported}

\subsection{\LaTeX\ 2e}
\begin{latexenv} % Does not work, see definition comment
\additem[arg1,arg2,arg3]{A nice description. Value latexcounter: \the\value{latexcounter}}
\additem[arg1,arg2,arg3]{A nice description. Value latexcounter: \the\value{latexcounter}}
\additem[arg1,arg2,arg3]{A nice description. Value latexcounter: \the\value{latexcounter}}
\end{latexenv}

\subsection{\LaTeX\ 3}
Workaround maybe possible, see egreg's hack: \\http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/172426/13552
\begin{latexthreeenv} % Does not work, see definition comment
\additem[arg1,arg2,arg3]{A nice description. Value latexthreecounter: \the\value{latexthreecounter}}
\additem[arg1,arg2,arg3]{A nice description. Value latexthreecounter: \the\value{latexthreecounter}}
\additem[arg1,arg2,arg3]{A nice description. Value latexthreecounter: \the\value{latexthreecounter}}
\end{latexthreeenv}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

### Log

The point of this is to demonstrate which counters are working as expected. We expect: 0,3,3,2,1.

#### Plain TeX

```
**** Value texcounter (before first call of body): 0
**** Value texcounter (after first call of body): 3
**** Value texcounter (inside additemx): 3
**** Value texcounter (inside additemx): 2
**** Value texcounter (inside additemx): 1
```

#### `Environ`

```
**** Value latexNewEnvironcounter (before first call of body): 0
**** Value latexNewEnvironcounter (after first call of body): 3
**** Value latexNewEnvironcounter (inside additemlatexNewEnviron): 3
**** Value latexNewEnvironcounter (inside additemlatexNewEnviron): 2
**** Value latexNewEnvironcounter (inside additemlatexNewEnviron): 1
```

#### Standard LaTeX `\newenvironment`

```
**** Value latexcounter (before first call of body): 0
**** Value latexcounter (after first call of body): 0
**** Value latexcounter (inside additemlatex): 0
**** Value latexcounter (inside additemlatex): -1
**** Value latexcounter (inside additemlatex): -2
```

#### `xparse`'s  `\NewDocumentEnvironment`

```
**** Value latexthreecounter (before first call of body): 0
**** Value latexthreecounter (after first call of body): 0
**** Value latexthreecounter (inside additemlatexthree): 0
**** Value latexthreecounter (inside additemlatexthree): -1
**** Value latexthreecounter (inside additemlatexthree): -2
```