# Detect \end of an environment

Tags: macros, expl3, latex3, arguments, parsing

I'm trying to create a macro that grabs everything till the end of the current environment and parses it. At first, I just want to put `!` right after my macro and another one `!` before the end of current environment.

Plain TeX delimited argument macro approach

```latex
\def\scanNext#1\end{#1\end}
```

LaTeX3 weird argument approach

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set:Npn \scan_next:w #1 \end {
#1\end
}
\newcommand{\scanNext}[1]{\scan_next:w #1}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Both of them work pretty well if the delimited token something different than `\end`, but with `\end` lead to an error. I believe that's because `\begin{...}` looks for `\end{...}` before `\scanNext` is executed.

Is it possible to create such a macro that wouldn't omit `\end`?

In addition to errors that it cause, there also might be a problem with nested environments. I guess I need to use check for `\@currenvir` somehow as well.

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set:Npn \scan_next:w #1 \end {
!#1!\end
}
\newcommand{\scanNext}[2]{\scan_next:w #1}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\def\scanNext#1c{!#1c!}

\begin{document}


\begin{gather} % \label{eq:abcd}
    x = \scanNext y
    \\
    \begin{cases}
        a\\
        b
    \end{cases}
    \\
    c=d
\end{gather}


\end{document}
```

Here's the expected result

[image]

Comment: You will want to look at the `+b` argument type in `ltcmd`: did you look at this?

Comment: @JosephWright can't find documentation about it. Could you share the link or post an example as an answer?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172398/collecting-environment-content-with-support-for-xparse-arguments

Comment: @JosephWright It's an argument for `xparse` environment. I just looked up in the docs and it says that `b` argument cannot be used with macros, so it won't help creating my `\scanNext` macro.

Comment: @user202729 I'm still getting errors. Could you leave an example as an answer to this post?

Comment: @user202729 it causes errors as well. I'm trying to create a macro that would capture everything till the end of current environment. It's the main goal now, afterwards I'm going to parse all of that, apply some regex replacements etc.

Comment: @user202729 ahh, you're right. Not the best example. I'll edit really quick.

Comment: Correction, it seems less `halign` and more like `\begin` absorb the argument and expand to something that does not contain an `\end` at all... so your requirement might be impossible, unless you put the macro somewhere before the whole environment...

Comment: i.e. the reason why you can't find the \end is similar to the one in this example https://pybin.pw/AIpRZ-iOUoVo0W7WY9uMdCQWBNuh.tex
, the \end already disappear when your environment is executed. So as I explained above, write something before the whole environment, or use something to preprocess the whole document

Comment: @user202729 if I put `\scanNext` before `\begin{...}` and use this solution then it works but stops at the first `\end{...}`, so if won't work as expected in case there're nested environments.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately you have to count the number of begin/end manually. (A simpler solution would be to match until the end environment name is the same as the begin environment name, but if some environment nest inside itself then it will still fail.)

Comment: Are you willing to pursue a LuaLaTeX-based approach? Or does it have to be based on pdfLaTeX? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico I'm glad you asked first before spending time on Lua based solution. Acually I'm not a big fan of it, so I prefer versatile solution that doesn't rely on the compilator, so I stick with pdflatex.

Comment: `\documentclass{article}\newcommand\macro[1]{Begin:#1:End}\NewDocumentEnvironment{environment}{+b}{\macro{#1}}{}\begin{document}\begin{environment}Body of environment\end{environment}\end{document}`

Comment: An xparse-macro cannot grab a +b-type argument. But an environment can and when it has done so it can pass the tokens as m-type-argument to a macro which grabs m-type-argument. But `\verb`/`verbatim` etc are a problem with this approach.

Comment: @UlrichDiez my goal is to create **macro**, that's why I posted the question. Otherwise I could create an environment and perform all the parsing inside without `\macro` bottleneck.

Comment: You need a generic macro which as its argument gathers the remainder of the current environment wherein it occurs. Probably this can be derived from the mechanism used by environments for gathering the content of an environment via a `+b`-argument. Such a mechanism will also gather (and thus tokenize) environments nested into the current one if in the current environment occurring after the macro that gathers the remainder of the current environment. If such environments, like verbatim or listings, rely on having their content tokenized after changing the catcode-régime, they are broken.